# Как завершить программу в Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как завершить программу в Python, и чтоб консоль не закрывалась, а выдавало сообщение

```
username = ["Vitalik L.", "Normal G.", "Grey T."]
parol = ["1234"]
Wh = input("Ваше имя: ")
if Wh in username:
    prl = input("Введите пароль: ")
    if prl in parol:
        print("В доступе разрешено!")
```

И чтоб если пароль и логин совпадали то программа давала доступ к дальнейшему коду, а если нет то программа выдавала текст "Неверный логин или пароль" и закрывала доступ к дальнейшему коду

Answer (score 3):

```
username = ["Vitalik L.", "Normal G.", "Grey T."]
parol    = ["1234"]
prl      = None

Wh = input("Ваше имя: ")

if Wh in username:
    prl = input("Введите пароль: ")

if prl in parol:
    print("В доступе разрешено!")
    # Делайте что-нибудь
else:
    print("Что-то пошло не так.")
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Мне надо чтоб если Логин или пароль были неверны то программа досрочно завершалась но с сообщением "Ошибка" или тому подобное. Пояснение: Если использовать команду sys.exit то консоль просто закрывается, а мне надо чтоб выдавало какое-то сообщение

Comment: @Spr1ng Я вас не понял, сообщение `Что-то пошло не так.` вас не устраивает ?